# Найти последний отрицательный элемент массива и заменить его индексом

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужно вывести последний отрицательный элемент массива и после заменить его на его же индекс.

*Если последний отрицательный элемент -2 по индексу 5, то вывести сначала -2 и после заменить значение на 5.*

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

int Y[5];
int X[5];
int i;

int main(void)
{
    printf("zapolnite massiv \n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &X[i]);
    }
    printf("____________________");
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (X[i] < 0)
        {
            (Y[i] = X[i]);
            printf("\n%d ", Y[i]);
        }
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Обратный цикл сделайте, т.е. от большего к меньшему, берете первый попавший что меньше нуля, меняете его значение на то что будет у вас в переменной `i`, выходите из цикла `break`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::istringstream is{line};
    std::vector<int> arr{std::istream_iterator<int>{is}, std::istream_iterator<int>{}};

    const auto negative = [&arr](auto i) { return arr[i] < 0; };

    for (auto i : std::views::iota(decltype(arr)::size_type{}, arr.size())
                | std::views::filter(negative)
                | std::views::reverse
                | std::views::take(1)) {
        std::cout << "element: " << arr[i] << "; index: " << i << '\n';
        arr[i] = static_cast<int>(i);
    }

    std::copy(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int X[5];
    int i;

    printf("zapolnite massiv \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &X[i]);
    }

    printf("____________________");

    for (i = 5; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (X[i] < 0)
        {
            printf("\n%d ", X[i]);
            X[i] = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n____________________");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d ", X[i]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```