# Вывести элементы массива с 5 по 10 в С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Я только недавно начал изучать С++ и уменя встал такой вопрос как мне можно вывести элементы массива например с 5 по 10? Я знаю что в Python есть такой синтаксис: array[5:10:]. В С++ такого случайно нет? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Цикл - типа, `for(int i = 5; i < 10; ++i) cout << a[i] << endl;`

Comment: А затем каждый цикл добавлять новый элемент в строку, а потом её можно вывести?

Comment: Можно и так... Как удобнее.

Comment: На ответ dIm0n советовал бы не смотреть до изучения С++ до достаточно высокого уровня. Его ответы работают, но ясности, особенно для начинающих, совершенно не прибавляют.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суббота не удастся, если в ответ на простой вопрос ни кто не помянет boost в купе с каким-нить функциональным алгоритмом:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/sliced.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>

#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// ...

using namespace boost::adaptors;

std::vector<int> arr{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11};

boost::copy(
    arr | sliced(5, 10),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
```

---

Подробности см. [в документации](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html#range.reference.adaptors.reference.sliced.sliced_example).

Answer (score 4):

Самый простой способ:

```cpp
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
} //=> 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr std::array arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for (decltype(arr)::size_type i = 5; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9
>
> 10

Также можно сделать свой класс (как в expression templates, например), где перегрузить оператор `()` для двух параметров, чтобы получить наиболее близкий синтаксис `std::cout << my_arr(5, 10);`

Comment: `decltype(arr)::size_type` Признавайтесь, вы в своем коде так же пишите (вместо `std::size_t`), или это в образовательных целях? :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat конечно, строгая типизация, const-корректность, все дела :) У меня почти весь код шаблонный, поэтому `using size_type = container::size_type` в помощь. Я считаю, что надо новичкам сразу привыкать к этому. Если что-то будет непонятно, то можно спросить в комментах или поискать, что это значит. В этом же и состоит обучение :)

Answer (score 1):

C++ вообще не отличается краткостью синтаксиса. Проще всего взять обычный цикл, как уже предложили в соседнем ответе: `std::for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) cout << arr[i] << endl;`.

Самое близкое к тому, что вы хотите, это [`#include <ranges>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) из C++20:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    int ints[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
 
    for (int x : ints | std::views::take(10) | std::views::drop(5))
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Но тут писать даже больше, чем в обычном `for`...

• `for` c `:` - это цикл по всем элементам массива или чего-то еще (гуглить по названию "range-based for").
• `take(10)` - берет первые 10 элементов.
• `drop(5)` - пропускает первые 5 элементов.
Если сначала поставить `drop(5)`, а потом `take(10)`, то получите элементы с 5 по 15, а не с 5 по 10.

---

Еще один вариант: (спасибо @dIm0n)

```
for (int i : std::views::iota(5, 10))
    std::cout << ints[i] << '\n';
```

Comment: Да, с ренджами тоже можно. Но [так](https://godbolt.org/z/8f98Th) проще, имхо. Вот в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1168343/398802) использовал подобное

Comment: @dIm0n Добавил.